# "TypeError: float argument required, not dict" Error for searching bing

Tags: python

I have a simple code to get urls from bing search.

```
import requests    
URL = "https://mykey:mykey@api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Web?$format=json&Query='%27heythere%27'"
API_KEY = 'mykey'
def request(query, **params):
    r = requests.get(URL % {'query': query}, auth=('', API_KEY))
    print r.content, r.status_code
    return r.json()['d']['results']   

r = request("JohnDalton")
print r.status_code

print r[0]['Url']
```

This returns the error as mentioned above for the line

```
r = requests.get(URL % {'query': query}, auth=('', API_KEY))
```

If you go to the link in URL you are prompted to give the key which workd fine, it returns the urls on the browser.

Comment: Does `r = requests.get(URL, data={'query': query}, auth=('', API_KEY))` work for you?

Comment: @Alberto Megia indentation is fine in the code.@JamieBull no it doesn't.

Comment: NOW is correct, when I saw it, it was not :)

Comment: Don't ask the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18174065/102441) twice

Answer (score 1):

Your format string `...at=json&Query='%27heythe...` contains [the format specifier `%27he`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18174827/102441), which prints a `float`. You give your format string a `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
URL = "https://mykey:mykey@api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Web?$format=json&Query='%(query)s'"

res = URL % {'query': "JoeDalton"}
print res
```

Getting:

```
https://mykey:mykey@api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Web?$format=json&query='JoeDalton'
```

If you want to format a string with a dict, you have to indicate key's name with %(key_name)s. If you only want to use one parameter to string format, I would use only "%s" and format it with "URL % "JoeDalton"

Hope it helps :)