# Replace variable in url for bing search

Tags: python

I have a code to get urls from bing search.

```
import requests
URL = "https://mykey:mykey@api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Web?$format=json&Query='query'"
API_KEY = 'mykey'
query = "JohnDalton"
def request(query, **params):
    query = ('%27'+query+ '%27')
    r = requests.get(URL % {'query': query}, auth=('', API_KEY))
    print r.content
    return r.json()['d']['results']


r = request("JohnDalton")

print r[0]['Url']
```

The script only gets urls related to "query" which i have put in the url, Even though i have tried replacing the value with the vairable query in the line;

```
r = requests.get(URL % {'query': query}, auth=('', API_KEY))
```

Why is it not replacing the values?

Answer (score 1):

That string formatting code isn't working.
Try this instead:

```
URL = "https://mykey:mykey@api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Web?$format=json&Query=%s"
get(URL % urllib.quote(query, safe='~()*!.\'')) # Don't forget to urlencode it
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the format string to use `%(query)s` where you want to replace stuff. See the following -

```
>>> 'My name is %(name)s' % {'name': 'Monty Python'}
'My name is Monty Python'
```

Or by using `format(...)` as follows -

```
>>> 'My name is {name}'.format(name='Monty Python')
'My name is Monty Python'
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't build the urls yourself - [`requests` can handle it](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls):

```python
API_KEY = 'mykey'
def request(query):
    # quotes are for whole-phrase matching - don't escape them here
    query = '"'+query+ '"'

    # let requests build your URL
    r = requests.get(
        'https://mykey:mykey@api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Web',
        params={'$format': 'json', 'Query': query},
        auth=('', API_KEY)
    )

    print r.content
    return r.json()['d']['results']
```

Comment: this program on running doesn't return anything