# What does 'h' mean in a python format string?

Tags: python, string-formatting

This is a valid python format string:

```
>>> wierd_format = '[%27he]'
>>> print wierd_format % 2.5
[        2.500000e+00]
```

But this isn't:

```
>>> bad_format = '[%20qe]'
>>> print bad_format % 2.5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 5, in <module>
    print bad_format % 2.5
ValueError: unsupported format character 'q' (0x71) at index 4
```

Clearly, `h` is a supported format character. However, the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) doesn't mention an `h` specifier. What does it do?

Comment: [ideone showing validity](http://ideone.com/EfhqWK)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs:

> A length modifier (`h`, `l`, or `L`) may be present, but is ignored as it is not necessary for Python – so e.g. `%ld` is identical to `%d`.

Answer (score 3):

[Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) say that it is a length modifier.

> A length modifier (h, l, or L) may be present, but is ignored as it is not necessary for Python. so e.g. %ld is identical to %d.

They seem the same,

```
>>> "[%he]" %2.5
'[2.500000e+00]'
>>> "[%le]" %2.5
'[2.500000e+00]'
>>> "[%Le]" %2.5
'[2.500000e+00]'
```

Comment: Whoops, I'm blind. That documentation link is more out of date than mine, but both contain the string

Comment: @Eric : Thanks. Updated it to the newer one. :)

Comment: @Eric : I could also find the `h` modifier in TcL. There may be a relation here, but, not sure. Here's the [link](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/format.htm). Quoted -> `If it is h it specifies that the numeric value should be truncated to a 16-bit value before converting.`